# Cant set up php enviroment in Docker

Tags: laravel, docker, ubuntu-20.04, windows-11, laravel-sail

When I run

`docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/opt -w /opt laravelsail/php81-composer:latest composer install`

to install all the composer `dependencies`,

these popped up

```
~/Crowdstage$ docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/opt -w /opt laravelsail/php81-composer:latest composer install
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Verifying lock file contents can be installed on current platform.
Your lock file does not contain a compatible set of packages. Please run composer update.

  Problem 1
    - spatie/image is locked to version 2.2.2 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - spatie/image 2.2.2 requires ext-exif * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's exif extension.
  Problem 2
    - spatie/laravel-medialibrary is locked to version 10.3.4 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - spatie/laravel-medialibrary 10.3.4 requires ext-exif * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's exif extension.

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    -
    - /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-bcmath.ini
    - /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-pcntl.ini
    - /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-sodium.ini
    - /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-zip.ini
You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

What is the proper way to set up PHP environment in docker for laravel ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can install composer dependencies in a cloned project

`docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/opt -w /opt laravelsail/php81-composer:latest composer install --ignore-platform-reqs`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to run `composer install` inside the php container. You can do this by running

```sh
docker-compose exec laravel.test "composer install"
```

if laravel.test [is the container name](https://github.com/laravel/sail/blob/1.x/stubs/docker-compose.stub#L4)